# PHP Include is not working if i use ajax jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a file named index.php in which My Ajax is-->

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#tokensubmit").submit(function(e){
            var id = $("#id").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "requests/abcd.php",
                    data: {login:true,id: id},
                    success: function(response){
                                alert(response);
                            }
                        }
                }); 
            e.preventDefault();
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

& OTHER FILE I HAVE WHICH IS "abcd.php" where i am sending ajax Request.
 abcd.php is like this ->

```
<?php  include 'xyz.php'; ?>
```

In xyz.php if i type

```
<?php echo "abcd ";?>
```

My ajax is not working ! 
What i want to say is **PHP INCLUDE** is **NOT** working with Ajax Request.

But without including xyz.php in abcd.php If i write the code directly which is in xyz.php without including .. Everything is working fine..

But i want to include the file.
How can i do that ? please help..

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a little more information. Your xyz.php file, where is it located?

Comment: in your abcd.php file, is INCLUDE the first instruction?

Comment: There are multiple possible explanations. Maybe the PHP script fails with some error and you have your environment set to supress those errors. Maybe the include path isn't correct. Maybe something else, but with correct paths your code is working on my machine

Comment: The problem is solved ! if you are calling abcd.php through ajax then abcd.php will require an absolute path .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are calling a file using ajax, then to include any other files on that file (abcd.php) will require an absolute path. For example :

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/file_folder/xyz.php';
```

Comment: Whether it's called with ajax or via the address bar in the browser has no impact on the path needed in the backend.

Comment: @Kevin B So what is your answer?

Comment: There is no answer, the OP hasn't included enough information for one to be provided.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. I've had the same problem in the past and solve the problem. Btw, thx for your down vote.

Comment: The code may solve the problem, but the answer contains provably incorrect information.

Comment: This downvoted answer was the solve from a Google search, so upvote it gets!

Comment: @SulungNugroho Your answer solved my problem, so 1 up-vote. Thank you very much!